# Replacements on selected text only works once

Tags: c#, string, replace, selected

I am trying to do replacements on selected text in a richtextbox.

It works fine but it only does it once.

If I want to do several replacements what should I do because I can't retain the selectedtext after it's been changed once?

I've tried the basic repeat command in the same method.

This works:

```
richTextBox1.SelectedText = richTextBox1.SelectedText.Replace("A", "B");
```

At this point `richTextBox1.SelectedText = ""` and it stops working on the line of code directly below in the same method:

```
richTextBox1.SelectedText = richTextBox1.SelectedText.Replace("C", "D");
```

Comment: immediately after posting this I found the answer (as is so typical of my mind). Create a string replacementtext = richTextBox1.SelectedText; at the top, do all the replacements you need in that, then do richTextBox1.SelectedText = replacementtext; at the end

Answer (score 2):

When you make the first replace the second one will not work because you are saving in the same "position"..

```
richTextBox1.SelectedText = richTextBox1.SelectedText.Replace("C", "D");
```

Save this into a string like this:

```
string replaced = richTextBox1.SelectedText.Replace("A", "B");

string replaced2 = richTextBox1.SelectedText.Replace("C", "D");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to *chain* the replacements (change `A` to `B` *and* `C` to `D`, finally assign the result back to `richTextBox1`)?

```
richTextBox1.SelectedText = richTextBox1.SelectedText
  .Replace("A", "B")
  .Replace("C", "D");
```

Comment: Yes and shortly after posting I figured it out, but thank you for that. very useful. New to programming so really appreciate it.